# HTTPS not supported in nsolid

Tags: node.js, nsolid

I'm playing with new NSolid tools because I'd like to know if we can use it in the company I work for.
We already have a nodejs application in production since last year and we're going to launch another one in the near future.

I've installed nsolid in a linux virtual machine and gave it a try with our current published app, but I'm having this problem with HTTPS requests we make from our application to other corporate services.

`[Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:".] 'Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:".
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:53:11)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:163:15)`

Is https module not supported by nsolid?
If that's the case, is there any plan about supporting it?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems unrelated to N|Solid, how are you doing the https request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems **nsolid** does not have any restriction regarding **https** protocol.

I was testing our application and found out that, disabling the use of a custom outgoing request we were using (agentkeepalive@0.1.5), the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

It seems unrelated to N|Solid, this error happens when you try to do an `https` request using an `http` client, I reproduced this error on different Node.js versions (v0.12.x, v4.x, N|Solid):

```
⬢  ~  node
> http.get("https://github.com/julianduque", function (res) {})
Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:".
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:53:11)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
    at Object.exports.get (http.js:35:21)
    at repl:1:6
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:164:27)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:392:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

How are you doing the request?

Comment: When I run the code of my current application without nsolid it does not raise that error. I double checked I'm using the 'https' module when using https protocol URLs.
I will try to dig deeper to provide more information.

Comment: also what version of Node are you running?

Comment: I'm using node version 0.10.21 in production.
These tests I'm doing are with nsolid (node 4.1.2).

Comment: I think I found something: we're using agentkeepalive@0.1.5 with our requests (we have one instance for plain request and another one for secure ones).
If I don't use the custom agent, https requests do work with no error.

Comment: Yes, in 0.10.21 the error is different. So you found why it's failing? Good! If you have any other N|Solid related question feel free to ask :D